# Selecting sparse number of predictors each derived from a non-sparse b-spline in time

Tags: regression-coefficients, lasso, regularization, splines

I have observations that I would like to model as responses at stations to slowly time-varying inputs at 80 candidate locations, few (perhaps 5-10?) of which are active and significant. I have observations and can model the responses at observation locations using a numerical model producing integrated Greens functions. The system is linear, but the modeling context has some guesses and imperfections.

I was thinking of modeling the inputs as independent B-splines in time indexed discretely over the candidate locations. The whole things should come together as a regression. In performing that regression I would like to produce non-negative coefficients, which is required by the physics of the system. I would also like to produce a sparse set of candidates locations, but not assume anything within each spline. Is there a method that do that kind of group-wise sparsity?